# Variation of a $9$-digit string with digits from $0 - 9$

Tags: combinatorics

I've got an exercise where I have a $9$ digit string e.g. $123456789$ with every digit randomly between $0$ and $9$.
I want to find out how many combinations there are without repetition of whole string
For example:

- $123456789$
- $132456789$
- $213456789$
- ...
  should be counted as one because they have the same occurrence of numbers.

I've found this formula, but I don't think it's correct:

$${n+k - 1 \choose n}$$

If something is unclear just let me know and I'm happy for every help :)

EDIT:
Thank you all very much. It seems that

$${n+k - 1 \choose n}$$

was after all the right formula. To doublecheck I've implemented it in JS with a simple for loop, maybe someone wants to try it

```
const zeroPad = (num, places) => String(num).padStart(places, '0');

let count = [];
// pretty slow because of the big number
for (let i = 0; i <= 999999999; i++) {
  let padded = zeroPad(i, 9);
  padded = padded.split('').sort().join('');
  if (count.includes(padded)) {
    continue;
  } else {
    count.push(padded);
  }
}

console.log(count.length);
```

Comment: This site can use LateX formatting. Please check the "Edit" button to see how I replaced your image by a LateX-based formula.

Comment: @Dominique thanks it's my first time asking something and I didn't know LateX can be used.

Comment: In this formula, we need to assign a value to n and k ; maybe n is the length of the string, and k is the number of distincts letters in the alphabet ? (n=9, k=10) ? There is one solution, which is long : how many strings with 9 distinct digits, plus how many strings with 1 double + 7 single, plus how many strings with 2 doubles + 5 single etc etc ... You need to find all patterns, and count how many strings for each pattern. It is basic, but very long.

Comment: It is not very clear what the conditions are on your strings. What is 'without repetition of whole string'? Are your three examples the same because they agree in the 456789 substring? If so, will two strings be considered the same whenever any of the corresponding digits agree?

Comment: If you take @Lourrran's interpretation of  ${n+k - 1 \choose n}$ as $n$ being the length of strings and $k$ being the available choices, why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @Joshua, my understanding is that anagrams are consider as similar : $1233=3321=2331$ etc, but $1233 \ne1223$

Comment: Ok, but then all permutations of 1-9 are anagrams, so there is only one.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley 'without repetition' means that the count of individual numbers are the same it's the same. so in the example every number between 1-9 occures once. Another example would be 000000010 and 000000001. Does that make it more clear?
If I would 'sort' both strings it would return 000000001 and 000000001

Comment: Once we have decided to use digits 123456789, all anagrams are similar, it counts for 1. But we can choose 012345678, or 112345678 or 001122334 or 111234567 or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is how many nine-digit strings can be formed using the digits $0 - 9$ with repetition of digits permitted up to permutations of the digits.  Therefore, what matters here is how many times each digit appears in the string.  Thus, we seek the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 = 9 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers, where $x_i$ is the number of times the digit $i$ appears in the string, $0 \leq i \leq 9$.  Note that this is equal to the number of nine-digit strings with nondecreasing digits.

A particular solution of equation $1$ corresponds to the placement of nine sticks in a row of nine stones.  For instance,
$$| \bullet \bullet | | \bullet \bullet \bullet | | \bullet | | \bullet \bullet | | \bullet$$
corresponds to the nondecreasing string $113335779$ or, in your formulation, a string containing two $1$s, three $3$s, one $5$, two $7$s, and one $9$.

The number of such strings is the number of ways we can place nine sticks in a row of nine stones, which is
$$\binom{9 + 10 - 1}{10 - 1} = \binom{18}{9}$$
since we must choose which nine of the $18$ positions required for nine sticks and nine stones will be filled with sticks.  Alternatively, we can write this as
$$\binom{9 + 10 - 1}{9} = \binom{18}{9}$$
since we must choose which nine of the $18$ positions required for nine sticks and nine stones will be filled with stones.  The latter formulation corresponds to your formula
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{n}$$
if we take $n = 9$ to be the length of the string and $k = 10$ to be the number of types of objects which can be used in the string.

Comment: Thank you. You have explained it very understandable.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it seems clear that it is combinations, not permutations that you are seeking.

Consider $10$ distinct bins numbered $0\; through\;9$ in which we are to put $9$ identical balls, with the balls getting labelled according to the bin in which they are put.

This is a classic [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem which will have the solution $$\binom{9+10-1}9 = 48620$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. N. F. Taussig's answer was a bit more understandable for me because of that I accepted that answer.

Comment: @Yingrjimsch: I didn't think you would need a more detailed explanation. Anyway, glad to have been of some help !